# C++ wget multi platform code

Tags: c++, wget

All,

my app has to download http://host/file.xml, let's say. The app is a C++ application that runs on Windows and Mac. Is there a good multi platform toolkit I can use for this or any other solutions? Just like wget on Unix.

Thanks

Comment: Wget runs perfectly on Windows too. Not sure about Mac. But using a library instead of an external tool is a better idea, as suggested in the answers.

Comment: `wget` is available for Mac OS X. It also has the BSD `fetch` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibCurl http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ might do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 2):

libcurl: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/